Subset columns from pandas dataframe that do not start with "X"
I'm trying to subset a dataframe by not selecting columns that I do not want that all start with the same phrase.  In other words I want the entire dataframe, except for columns that start with "death".
Say I have a dataframe with these columns



player
birthDay
birthMonth
birthYear
deathDay
deathMonth
deathYear



I've created a filter list for columns I don't want to select
cols = [col for col in df if col.startswith("death")]
df[~cols]

But when I run this I get the error: bad operand type for unary ~: 'list'
How come I am receiving this error?  And is there a better way of doing this?

the ~ operator does not work with a list, you either create a numpy/pandas array that supports the inversion operator, or you bake the inversion logic into the list comprehension - similar to the accepted answer

You can just reverse the logic to get a positive column list instead of a negative one:
cols = [col for col in df if not col.startswith("death")]
df[cols]


Yes you're very right I can do that.  I was stuck on trying to do it one way I didn't consider other options.  Thank you!

You can use filter with a regex pattern:
df.filter(regex="^(?!death)")


You can also use df.columns.str.startswith, select the inverse with ~, and apply boolean indexing with df.loc:
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.startswith('death')]

Note that all column labels need to be strings. If you're not sure, use columns.astype(str). Same is true for this option, incidentally.
